# Why does this code print only the first element?

Tags: perl

Can anyone explain to me why only the first item of this array is being printed?

```
    print "Hello World!\n";

    @array1 = ("john","haider","elley","uul");

    @array2 = qw/This is an array/;

    $array_size=scalar @array1;

    print "Size: ",$array_size,"\n";

    $i;

    for($i=0; $i<=$array_size; $i=$i+1)
    {
             print"Array elements are=",$array1[i],"\n";
    }
```

Comment: This is a great example of an error that `use strict` and `use warnings` would have caught. Why didn't you use them?

Comment: Hey Thanks for answering!! actually i am new to Perl so can you please tell me why its not printing all the elements.

Comment: Indeed, always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`. This will identify five or more problems in your program!

Comment: @DeendayalAhirwar: I didn't explain what the problem was, as you already had a really good answer from Sobrique.

Answer (score 5):

Because you've typo'ed here: `$array1[i]`.

That should be `$i`, as in `$array1[$i]` - and this is something that `use strict;` `use warnings` would have warned you about. `Bareword "i" not allowed while "strict subs" in use`

But as it stands - because you use `i` there, and it's not a variable - it's evaluated as zero, so you just print the first element of the array.

A better idiom would be:

```
foreach my $value ( @array1 ) { 
    print "Array elements are=", $value,"\n"; 
}
```

It is rarely necessary (or desirable) to manipulate arrays by index in perl.

Comment: But if i will use $i it will print value of i that is 0 to 4....correct me if i am wrong